# SPO vs PnP on classic / modern experience

Tags: pnp-powershell, modern-experience, classic-experience

Are there any limitations using  [SPO managment shell commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps) or [PnP commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) to manage SharePoint Online site, based on classic or modern experience?

Problem underneath the question - I have a script that reads information about list items (ID and Title) based on URL and there seems to be a problem with different sites (one is classic experience, other is modern).

(answer for example, "No - You cannot get list items from modern experience site using SPO".)

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no difference on classic or modern experience when working with core list and library features with the tools. The biggest issues would be around permissions as Modern Sites have a different security model (AD and SP groups vs Office 365 Groups).

The break between the two tools:

- The focus of the SPO cmdlets is administration from the Site Collection up. (Creating Site Collections, etc.)
- The focus of the PNP cmdlets is the Site(web) on down. (Working with lists, libraries and content.)

> I have a script that reads information about list items (ID and Title) based on URL and there seems to be a problem with different sites (one is classic experience, other is modern).

What's the problem? The default (internal) names of the columns? What's the list type?

Comment: Problem underneath is hard to unfold and it should be discussed in another question. Thank You for the explanation.